# Debugging/Reformatting a replacement jquery js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In very basic terms, where does someone experienced in HTML, CSS & JS start looking for errors in the formatting of various JS plugins?

For example, I'm working with a couple of different templates that went in tandem with a youtube tutorial on Expression Web 4 from the Timothy Framework series.  Now that I've completed the tutorial site design, which included a basic jquery slider and lightbox effect, I'm trying to replace those slider and lightbox effects with a different version.  For the question's sake, let's say I'm trying to replace the Magnific-Popup plugin with a Feature-List plugin.

The file structure has been updated with the needed photos and linked correctly.  The CSS and JS files are in place and linked correctly.  The script activates more or less correctly in any given browser, but the formatting is all off.  My text and various images aren't lining up correctly.

I believe there's probably a conflict in the div that contains the Feature-List plugin between the pages main CSS file and the plugin specific css, but I'm hoping someone can give me some general guidance as to where they would start to look to debug/reformat the plugin.

I can copy my code or be more specific, but I'm really looking for just some general thought process ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/, http://www.jshint.com/, [devtools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Comment: Look [this](http://www.jslint.com/).

Comment: I'd agree with @elclanrs, except that he wrote them in the wrong order: first look at and understand your code (you can't debug code you can't see), next try it out and try to find issues with your browser developer tools and finally, pass your code through the various validators/lint tools.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses guys.  It's sincerely appreciated.

Comment: What I basically did was download the complete file structures from a couple of different templates.  Each one was developed as a full working site - You just adjust as needed.  Once I got through the basic tutorial, I wanted to take a js plugin from one template and put it in place of the js on another.  The js code and js css should be correct - it works on it's original template site. I think the format is just getting conflicted between my main css and the js css files on my hybrid of the 2 templates.  I just don't know where to start looking.  Should probably learn the code better 1st